# Copy autofiltered cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a script that will do several things. I used the macro to do the basics, but I'm trying to find code for the rest. I have a worksheet of 15 columns and many rows(this worksheet gets made by another program and will change each time I run it). I have to go through it and delete certain things. I need a script that will

1. Delete Row 2 (it's always useless)--Done
2. Give column N a width of 10--Done
3. Make Column D a number with 5 digits--Done
4. Set Autofilters--Done
5. Find all rows where column O contains either a blank or a "U" --Done
6. Cut and paste those rows from the original worksheet into a new one within the same workbook
7. Autofilter so that Column M is in order from smallest to largest
8. Have a popup asking what the maximum is
9. Cut and paste any row where column M contains a higher number than you entered in the popup, after the first paste.
10. Filter column K to only show the rows where column K contains a blank
11. Put those in order by date, column N
12. Cut and paste as before any row where column N contains a date from before the first day of the month six months ago (for example, today, that would be Mar 1, 2014)
13. Delete all columns but D and E in the second worksheet.

I have code for all of the actions, I just need to get popup dialog boxes for the max (step 8 above) and for the date (step 12 above). I have used 5 different scripts. The first does the formatting steps at the beginning (1-4). The second does the "U" search (5-6). The third does the Max search (7-9), the fourth does the final search (10-12). The fifth does a cleanup on the second sheet (13).

I'd assume  when I get the dialog boxes in, that I would assign the answer given in the dialog boxes to variables, and use that in the code? How would I go about that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried already? SO is not a free software development service, but if you're stuck at a certain point in finding a solution we could help you a lot better if you showed your progress so far.

Answer (score 1):

you're asking for a lot of steps here, my advice to start would be to break up your code. You have 13 distinct things that you are aiming to do I would write each one of them individually. It looks to me based on your code that you are using the macro recorder to get the result you want and then reverse engineering what the macro recorder produces and VBA for you.

So here's a quick step that can get you going.

I would create a main class

```
Sub Main()
call Macro4()
End Sub


Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
'
'Delete Row 2
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("N6").Select
'Show full dates
Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit
'Engage Autofilter
Selection.AutoFilter
'Make the Account Number format 5 digits
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "00000"
'Show All in Column O (single status) to be deleted
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("50100").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("50100").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "O1:O4222"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("50100").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("O5").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$10000").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="=U", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
End Sub
```

in order to help you more I need the tab name for you sheets could you post a copy and I will look at tomorrow.

Comment: Since I just wanted to get as much done as possible, I did end up making several different ones (1-5, 7, 10-11, 13), and all that I need to figure out is how to get it to cut and paste the things shown by the autofilter into a new worksheet, and to bring a popup to ask for the date and max. Then, would it be realistic to attach them all together?